# Event defined as a set of sets

Tags: probability, statistics

i'm studing the Probability Theory and i came to the concept of Event.

To me, it seems that an event can be represented as a set of sets, where every single element of the set represent a possible outcome of the event.
For example,if i roll 2 dies and i want the event that at every roll each die has to be a value < 3, i can represent the event as:

$E=\left \{ \left \{ 1,1 \right \},\left \{ 1,2 \right \},\left \{ 2,1 \right \},\left \{ 2,2 \right \} \right \}$

Is it ok to represent an Event in this way, or other representations are better ?

Comment: The problem is that $\{1,1\}=\{1\}$ and $\{2,1\}=\{1,2\}$. What you are looking for is a set of sequences, or at least a set of ordered pairs if you only roll twice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila is right, if the order of the event matters, you should represent the event as a ordered pair instead of a set.

Comment: Events are sets made of outcomes. Outcomes are elements of the set $\Omega$ called the probability space. Thus, events are subsets of the probability space $\Omega$. A natural choice of probability space $\Omega$ for the roll of two dice is $$\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots,6\}^2=\{(i,j)\mid i\in\{1,2,\ldots,6\},j\in\{1,2,\ldots,6\}\}$$

Comment: Choosing for $\Omega$ the set of subsets of size $1$ or $2$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$ is also possible if one does not wish to separate the results $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ for $i\ne j$, but then the outcomes $\{i\}$ and $\{i,j\}$ would probably have different probabilities. All in all, in most cases, a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to represent $E=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ for the aforementioned reasons above, $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$ but $(1,2)\neq(2,1)$.

Comment: Perfect, so the elements inside the set are tuples ?

Comment: Yes! Totally right, then it all works